# How to evaluate the reach of an open source project when there are 0 projects in its repo dependents?

Tags: github, dependencies, software-use

I am constantly using open source projects during my work.

Usually I view the [dependents graph](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/exploring-the-dependencies-of-a-repository#dependents-view) to see which other open source projects use it.

However, How do I gauge the reach of a project such as [`python-poetry`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry)?

 As there are 0 dependents in [its repo dependents graph](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/network/dependents), but I am quite sure that a lot of projects use it.

Comment: Stars are potentially related to downstream use, especially when trying to estimate closed-source use. [Libraries.io](https://libraries.io/pypi/poetry) often has more detailed statistics. GitHub's dependency graph feature depends on scanning `requirements.txt` files which has inherent limitations.

Answer (score 3):

It's more of an art than a science, but there are a few metrics that may be useful to look at:

- Stars on GitHub. A star is essentially someone showing their appreciation and interest in the project.
- Watchers on GitHub. Watching a project essentially says you want to be notified of any change in the repository.
- Forks on GitHub. A fork is the starting point of someone (openly) working on a project in GitHub.

As noted, none of these metrics are iron clad (e.g., you could watch a project but ignore updates from it, or fork a project and do nothing with this fork), but they are somewhat of an indicator of interest.

It's also usually a good idea to normalize these numbers by comparing to similar projects, as the absolute numbers are sometimes hard to interpret. E.g., let's look at Python's [psychopg2](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2) library for connecting to PostgreSQL databases. At the time of writing, it has 73 watchers, 464 forks and 2.8K forks. Is this a lot? a little? Hard to tell from the numbers alone. But if you compare it to the [mysql-connector-python](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python) library for connecting to MySQL databases, you'll see similar numbers, but if you compare it to [db2-python](https://github.com/IBM/db2-python) for connecting to DB2 database, you'll see substantially smaller numbers. This is a strong indicator that PostgreSQL and MySQL are more popular databases to use in Python applications that DB2.